# Exporting Labelled double <dbl+lbl> data type

Tags: r, tidyverse, tibble

After importing an SPSS `.sav` file, the resulting tibble reports itself as follows:

```
# A tibble: 88,528 x 7
       CRY12    CRYOX7   INDS07M  INECAC05    SOC10M    URESMC     GOR9D
   <dbl+lbl> <dbl+lbl> <dbl+lbl> <dbl+lbl> <dbl+lbl> <dbl+lbl>     <chr>
 1       997       578        NA        31        NA        11 E12000009
 2       921       926        NA        30        NA        11 E12000009
 3       921       926        NA        31        NA        11 E12000009
 4       372       372        NA        25        NA        11 E12000009
 5       372       372        17         1      2211        11 E12000009
 6       372       372        NA        34        NA        11 E12000009
 7       921       926        18         2      3411        11 E12000009
 8       921       926        NA        34        NA        11 E12000009
 9       997       392        NA        25        NA        11 E12000009
10       997       392         3         1      2136        11 E12000009
# ... with 88,518 more rows
```

If I ask to see just the `SOC10M` column, R reports that the variable is a `<Labelled double>` and shows me the Labels:

```
> df$SOC10M[1:10]
<Labelled double>
 [1]   NA   NA   NA   NA 2211   NA 3411   NA   NA 2136

    Labels:
     value                                                        label
        -9                                               Does not apply
        -8                                                    No answer
      1115                   1115  'Chief executives and Snr officials'
      1116                 1116  'Elected officers and representatives'
      1121      1121  'Production mngrs and directors in manufacturing'
      1122       1122  'Production mngrs and directors in construction'
      1123  1123  'Production mngrs and directors in mining and energy'
```

I couldn't find any documentation specific to this data type.

I'd like to export this to a csv which has the `label` each time, instead of the `value`. (i.e. the CSV should have strings instead of numbers, where appropriate.)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can find the documentation for this data type and *bridge* the SPSS-R gab using [haven](http://haven.tidyverse.org/articles/semantics.html).

From the documentation I've produced this example that I hope is self-explanatory.

```
# install.packages(c("haven"), dependencies = TRUE)
library(haven)
x1 <- labelled(c(1,NA, 5, 3, 5), c(Good = 1, Bad = 5) )
x2 <- labelled( c("M", "F", NA, "F", "M"),  c(Male = "M", Female = "F") )

df <- tibble(x1, x2)
df
#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>          x1        x2
#>   <dbl+lbl> <chr+lbl>
#> 1         1         M
#> 2        NA         F
#> 3         5      <NA>
#> 4         3         F
#> 5         5         M
#> > 

# kinda like you are doing
df$x1[1:3]
#> <Labelled double>
#> [1]  1 NA  5
#> 
#> Labels:
#>  value label
#>      1  Good
#>      5   Bad 

zap_labels(df$x1[1:3])
#> [1]  1 NA  5

as_factor(df$x2[1:3])
#> [1] Male   Female <NA>  
#> Levels: Female Male

zap_labels(df)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>      x1    x2
#>   <dbl> <chr>
#> 1     1     M
#> 2    NA     F
#> 3     5  <NA>
#> 4     3     F
#> 5     5     M
```